# Most efficient way to pack circles with different radii in a rectangle of given size

Tags: circles, rectangles, packing-problem

Given a rectangle of size $x$, $y$, I would like to fit the maximum circles in it.
The second rule is that my circles come in 3 different radii $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and I need the maximum number of triplets $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ filling my rectangle.

If that can help, the circle sizes are $r_1=9cm$, $r_2=12cm$, $r_3=16cm$,  and the rectangle vary in size. An example would be 130$\times$170 cm.

For a bit of context, I need to cut the maximum number of circle triplets out of a rectangle fabric. I don't want to waste any unnecessary fabric.

After some research I've realised that it is a very hard problem to solve, but I'd be happy with any algorithm, code, or formula giving me a rather good filling, even if it is not the optimal solution.

Here is my research so far :

- Packing identical circles in a square : I could simplify my problem by packing squares in a rectangle... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square
- I think the Circle packing theorem does not apply as I have a rectangle instead of large circle, different radii
- An other option is to do an approximation with square packing in rectangle...

Thanks a lot to those who'll help me with this :)

Comment: If you want to maximize the number of circles, you might as well restrict to the smallest radius.  Do you maybe instead want to maximize the sum of areas of circles?

Comment: Or do you need the same number of circles for each radius?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the precision, I need one of each radius

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to fit $11$ of each radius:
[image]

Comment: Oh that's awesome, thank you very much! How did you achieve that? I actually need to do that for several rectangle dimensions

Comment: I used an optimization solver, very similar to [this blog post](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/05/knapsack-packing-combinatorial-benders.html) but with an extra constraint to enforce the same number of circles for each radius.  See also my answer to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92949/my-mothers-dish-collection).